# How do I use grep to search the current directory for all files having a given string and then move these files to a new folder?

Tags: bash, unix, grep

I have managed to do this separately using

```
grep  -r "zone 19" path

mkdir zone19
find . -name "ListOfFilesfromGrep"  -exec mv -i {}  zone19 \;
```

I just don't know how to combine the two, that is, how to input the list of files I get from grep into the find command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `grep` from within `find`:

```
find /path/to/dir -type f -exec grep -q "zone 19" {} \; -exec mv -i {} zone19 \;
```

Comment: Nice answer, didn't know you could use the results of a previous exec in the next one.

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe the result from `grep` and use `xargs`:

```
grep  -lr "zone 19" path | xargs <command>
```

`<command>` will be applied on each result of `grep`. Note thta `-o` flag tells `grep` to show only matching parts.

Comment: Don't they want to move the file, not act on only the matched parts ?

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
grep -lr "zone 19" path | while read in ; do mv -i "$in" zone19; done
```

`-l` prints the filenames with matched string; `while ... done` move the files one by one.

Comment: You should double-quote `$in` to avoid problems with filenames with blanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU versions of the standard tools:

`grep -l` will give you the filenames.
`mv -t` will move to a given directory.
`xargs -r` will invoke a command using arguments from stdin, but only if there's at least one.

Combine them like this:

```
grep -l -r -e 'zone 19' path | xargs -r mv -i -t 'zone19'
```

Or (if your filenames might contain newlines etc):

```
grep -lZr -e 'zone 19' path | xargs -0r mv -it 'zone19'
```

Comment: Since you're assuming GNU utilities, you should render the command more robust by using `-Z` for `grep` and `-0` for `xargs`, so that the command doesn't fail on filenames containing spaces or quotes.

Comment: I get the error message "xargs: illegal option -- r"

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf - Yes, your comment crossed with my edit.

Comment: @Aline - I used the above command with xargs version 4.4.2 (from Ubuntu 14.04).  You can leave out the `-r` without harm (`mv` will just give an error message if you match no files).

Comment: Ok, thanks! I'm in OS X and just seen that some xargs options are missing.

Comment: True. Sorry, my bad!

Answer (score 0):

Below is the command to move all files containing string "Hello" to folder zone19.

```
grep Hello * |cut -f1 -d":"|sort -u|xargs -I {} mv {} zone19
```